# Matlab Regexp for nested groups and captured tokens

Tags: regex, matlab, token, regex-group

Is there a way to capture tokens inside a non-captured group in Matlab regular expressions? Here is the specific problem:

```
InputString = 'Identifiers: 10  12  1   3   8   6   4   2'

Expression = 'Identifiers:\s(?:(\d*)\t?)+'
regexp(InputString, Expression, 'tokens')
```

I need to find the numbers after 'Identifier'. The string InputString is part of a big character array with lines before and after this line, separated by \r\n characters. The character after the colon is a whitespace, the numbers are seperated by tabs. The last number has no trailing tab. The number of numbers can vary, but it's always at least one and only integers with 1 or n digits.

I had the following idea in my `Expression`: Identify line by `Identifiers:\s`, find numbers with n>1 digits and captured token and possible trailing tab by `(\d*)\t` and repeat this 1 or more times by `+`. To repeat the digit part expression, I need to put it in a group. But I don't want to capture the token of the outer group `(?:(\d*)\t?)`, but of course the token of the inner grouping `(\d*)`. Thats why I used `?:`. When I remove `?:` only one token containing `1012138642` is returned.

Isn't it possible to capture tokens inside a non-capturing group? Do you have any solution to return the numbers in a single statement?

In my current solution I find the line by

```
Expression = 'Identifiers:.+?\r\n'
Line = regexp(InputString, Expression, 'match')
```

and get the digits with

```
regexp(Line, '(\d+)\t+', 'tokens')
```

I spend so much time finding a single statement solution, I now really need to know if it's possible or not! I am not sure if I am thinking wrong, my head is not working as intended or it's just impossible.

Comment: Looks like `\G` operator is not supported in Matlab regex.  You need to do that in two steps.

Comment: `(?:(\d*)\t?)+` effectively quantifies group 1. The capture group will only contain the value from the last pass 9 8 7 6 5 `4` Also, everything in the non-capture group is optional, meaning nothing will be in group 1 that u will see. On open ended regex, there should be at least 1 required item. `(?:(\d+)\t?)+`

Comment: Regex 1 `'Identifiers:\s([\d\t]+)` take capture group 1, then run this on group 1 (previous) globally `\d+` then you're done.

Comment: If you really mean just a single line of command, I succeeded with this `transpose(sscanf(subsref(regexp(InputString, Expression, 'match'), struct('type','{}','subs',{{[1]}})),'%d'))`

Comment: Thank you very much. I should have specified that I wanted to find the numbers by a regular expression only. Still your answer is incredible Yvon, nice work, would never have found this solution. Thanks to all!

Answer (score 2):

MATLAB doesn't support nested tokens, even if you you mark them as non capturing.

Starting in 16b there are some new text manipulations that make this easier:

```
str = "Identifiers: 10  12  1   3   8   6   4   2" + newline + "Blah";

str = str.extractBetween("Identifiers: ",newline).split

str = 

  8×1 string array

    "10"
    "12"
    "1"
    "3"
    "8"
    "6"
    "4"
    "2"
```

If your goal is one statement with regexp, using split might get you closer.

```
str = regexp(str,'(?<=Identifiers[^\n]*)\s*(?=[^\n]*)','split')

str = 

  1×10 string array

    "Identifiers:"    "10"    "12"    "1"    "3"    "8"    "6"    "4"    "2"    "Blah"
```

Comment: Both nice solutions and way more satisfying than mine. Thank you very much for this. I will go with the first one.